# Is it possible to use COUNT with a DISTINCT JPA projection?

Tags: java, jpa

I am using a JPA distinct projection to get some data:

```
select distinct o.f1, o.f2, o.f3 from SomeEntity o where ...
```

This works fine with setFirstResult and setMaxResults to page data.

However I need to count the total number of rows without fetching all of them. I have tried:

```
select count(distinct o.f1, o.f2, o.f3) from SomeEntity o where ...
```

This does not work (with EclipseLink anyway) and it doesn't seem to be allowed by the JPA spec. Is there another way? I don't want to have to write an SQL query to do this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to do a distinct count in JPA critera API?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6197591/how-to-do-a-distinct-count-in-jpa-critera-api)

Answer (score 31):

Try this:

```
select count(distinct o) from SomeEntity o where ...
```

Comment: Just be careful not to use count(distinct(o)) - the extra bracket is an error

Answer (score 0):

If EclipseLink and your underlying DB allow subselects try:

```
select count(*) from (select distinct o.f1, o.f2, o.f3 from SomeEntity o where ... )
```

That way your can just put your JQL in to count its total result size.

This works for hibernate sql named queries.  I'll try it on JP-QL queries soon.

Answer (score -1):

Though this answer is coming late but it might help future people.
In your repository.
This worked for me in my own case.

@Query("SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(o.f1, o.f2...) FROM SomeEntity o WHERE....)

Hope it helps others.

Comment: I think it distincts only count numbers, not column values

Answer (score -5):

You say you don't want to write an SQL query to do this, but what is the difference between JPA QL and SQL? If you don't want to use the `getResultList().size()` method to determine the number of total rows, then the only way is to use a native sql query.

```
entityManager.createNativeQuery("select count(distinct o.f1, o.f2, o.f3) from SomeEntity o where ...").getSingleResult();
```

or

```
entityManager.createQuery("select distinct o.f1, o.f2, o.f3 from SomeEntity o where ...").getResultList().size();
```

Comment: There where clause is fairly complex and generates a lot of SQL. I don't want to have to maintain that myself. Also then I will have two versions of the same query, one in SQL for the count and one EJBQL to fetch a page of rows.

Comment: There is quiet a reason why JPQL exists and why it is usually recomended over native SQL. Using getResultList().size() if you only want to retrieve number of items is unefective and clumsy.