# QueryDSL Group By Row Count

Tags: java, sql, jpa, querydsl

I'm stuck in get the total count of group by query result.

```
JPAQuery jpaQuery = new JPAQuery(entityManager);
jpaQuery.from(QMessageSend.messageSend)
        .where(predicate)
        .groupBy(QMessageSend.messageSend.messageId).count();
```

this is my current code.
and this code return count for each group.

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM MESSAGE_SEND ms
GROUP BY ms.MESSAGE_ID
```

but I want to get the total count of group by query result.
like result of below sql

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM (
   SELECT *
   FROM MESSAGE_SEND ms
   GROUP BY ms.MESSAGE_ID
) msc
```

What I should do?

MESSAGE_ID is not primary key.
and JPAQuery's distinct method not support select specific column. (has no parameter)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `COUNT(DISTINCT)`:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT s.MESSAGE_ID)
FROM MESSAGE_SEND ms;
```

If `MESSAGE_ID` is the primary key in the table, then `COUNT(*)` suffices.

Comment: MESSAGE_ID is not primary key.
and JPAQuery distinct method not supporting select column. ;(

Comment: @chooco13 . . . I noticed the focus on JPA after I answered.  Does this answer the question?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6197591/how-to-do-a-distinct-count-in-jpa-critera-api.