# CriteriaQuery DISTINCT values in an aggregation function

Tags: spring-data-jpa, distinct, criteriaquery

### Introduction

Consider a query like the following:

```sql
SELECT
    building.name                                 AS building_name,
    STRING_AGG(DISTINCT visit.visitor_name, ', ') AS visitors,
    COUNT(visit.id)                               AS total_visits
FROM building
    LEFT JOIN visit
        ON building.id = visit.building_id
GROUP BY building.id
```

Note the `DISTINCT` keyword used in `STRING_AGG` aggregation function. The results could look something like the following:

```
+----------------------+-------------+--------------+
|    building_name     |  visitors   | total_visits |
+----------------------+-------------+--------------+
| Skyline Residence    | Edgar, John |            6 |
| Forbidden Residence  |             |            0 |
| Cloud Nine Residence | John        |            1 |
+----------------------+-------------+--------------+
```

The important part is that if John and Edgar have visited Skyline Residence 6 times, then the `visitors` column should not display their names multiple times like `John, Edgar, Edgar, Edgar, John, John`.

### JPA CriteriaQuery Code

This is my JPA `CriteriaQuery` code so far, **without `DISTINCT`**:

```java
CriteriaBuilder builder = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<ResultDto> query = builder.createQuery(ResultDto.class);

Root<Building> building = query.from(Building.class);
Join<Building, Visit> visit = building.join("visits", JoinType.LEFT);

query.select(builder.construct(
    ResultDto.class,
    building.get("name"),
    builder.function("STRING_AGG", String.class, visit.get("visitorName"), builder.literal(", ")),
    builder.count(visit.get("id")) //            ^ I need DISTINCT here ^
));

query.groupBy(building.get("id"));

final TypedQuery<ResultDto> typedQuery = getEntityManager().createQuery(query);
final List<ResultDto> resultList = typedQuery.getResultList();
```

How could I modify this code to generate the above SQL query, **with `DISTINCT`**?

Note: Do not answer with Hibernate's deprecated `Criteria` API solutions. It should be done using JPA's `CriteriaQuery`.

Comment: CriteriaQuery interface has a method named distinct with boolean parameter.

Comment: @lutfucan AFAIK this method is used to select distinct results over the entire result-set. How would I use it for my purposes?

Comment: Correct, it is used to distinct result set. I don' t know how to implement it over aggregates. But there is an answer to similar to your situation : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6197591/how-to-do-a-distinct-count-in-jpa-critera-api

Comment: @lutfucan That doesn't really help for Aggregates other than COUNT, which does have `javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder.countDistinct`. It seems like the JPA Criteria API is lacking in additional API for the other Aggregates that accept DISTINCT, as detailed in section 4.8 of the JPA Spec

Answer (score 1):

You can write a template for string_agg using MetadataBuilderContributor

```
public class SqlFunctionsMetadataBuilderContributor implements MetadataBuilderContributor {

@Override
public void contribute(MetadataBuilder metadataBuilder) {
    metadataBuilder.applySqlFunction(
            "string_agg_distinct",
            new SQLFunctionTemplate(StandardBasicTypes.STRING, "string_agg(distinct ?1, '; ')")
    );
}
```

}

And add in the properties:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.metadata_builder_contributor=<your-package>.SqlFunctionsMetadataBuilderContributor
```

And then use "string_agg_distinct" instead of "STRING_AGG" in function