# Multiple same table in join return wrong count vlaue

Tags: sql, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I use spring data jpa.

Actually, I have 3 tables.

```
public class LE
  @Id
  private Long eventId;

  @ManyToOne
  private PR pr;

  ...
}

public class PR
  @Id
  private Long prId;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy="pr")
  private PRBA prba;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy="pr")
  private List<LE> le;
  ...
}

public class PRBA{
  @Id
  private Long prbaId;

  @ManyToOne 
  private PR pr;

  @ManyToOne 
  private BA ba;

  private LocalDate date;
}

public class BA{
  @Id
  private Long baId;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy="ba")
  private List<PRBA> prba;
}
```

I wrote this jpql query

```
select count(le) from LE le
inner join le.pr pr
inner join p.prba prba
inner join p.prba prba2
where
pr.prId=1
and prba.baId!=prba2.baId
```

I search to get the number of Le who have same value for PR but with diferent value for BA

I have this database values

```
LE table
eventId prId
1       1
2       1

PR table
prId
1
2


PRBA table
prbaId prId baId
1      1    1
2      1    2

BA table
baId
1
2
```

Seem like query is not good because it return 4

Seem like a cartesian problem

I was expecting 2

Sql generated by hibernate is

```
select
        count(le.event_id) as col_0_0_ 
    from
        le le0 
    inner join
        pr pr1 
            on le0.pr_id=pr1.pr_id 
    inner join
        prba prba1 
            on pr1.pr_id=prba1.pr_id 
    inner join
        prba prba2 
            on pr1.pr_id=prba2.pr_id 
    where
        le0.pr_id=? 
        and prba1.ba_id<>prba2.ba_id
```

Comment: How `eventId` will 1 for multiple row, it is not your primary key ?. Check again as your data it will be `0`

Comment: my error don't wrote correct value fixed, but same issue

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT le) ...` should do the trick.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5339434/66686